# URL to get all recipes from two categories

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a recipes website. I need to list all recipes on an archive page, categorized, for exemple as lunch, which main ingredient is chicken.Ideally, the URL must be something like this: **[www.mywebsite.com/recipes/tagged/lunch+chicken](http://www.mywebsite.com/recipes/tagged/lunch+chicken)**

I have created a custom post type with the slug **recipes** and two custom taxonomies: **meal** and **ingredient**, linked to that custom post type. For that I'm using a plugin Custom Post Type UI.

At this moment:

- I can get an archive page with all recipes: [www.mywebsite.com/recipes](http://www.mywebsite.com/recipes)
- I can get an archive page with all lunch recipes: [www.mywebsite.com/lunch](http://www.mywebsite.com/lunch)
- I can get an archive page with all chicken recipes: [www.mywebsite.com/chicken](http://www.mywebsite.com/chicken)

How can I get a combination of both (lunch+chicken)? Is it possible to configure Custom Post Type UI for that?

Thanks in advance an happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Created a custom post type using the slug "`my-post-type-slug`".
Two different taxonomies were associated with the custom post type. Example:

Taxonomy 1: `Color`, Terms: `Red`, `White`, ...

Taxonomy 2: `Size`, Terms: `Small`, `Medium`, ...

Archive page url:
`host.tld/my-post-type-slug/`

You can manipulate this archive listing page.

```php
<?php
function custom_posts_filter_frontend( $query ){
    if( $query->is_main_query() ){
        if( is_post_type_archive( 'my-post-type-slug' ) ){ // replace with your custom post type slug
            $taxonomy1 = 'color'; // replace with your custom taxonomy slug
            $term1 = isset( $_GET[$taxonomy1] ) ? $_GET[$taxonomy1] : false;
            $taxonomy2 = 'size'; // replace with your custom taxonomy slug
            $term2 = isset( $_GET[$taxonomy2] ) ? $_GET[$taxonomy2] : false;
            $tax_query = array('relation' => 'AND');
            if( $term1 ){
                $tax_query[] = array(
                        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy1,
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $term1,
                );
            }
            if( $term2 ){
                $tax_query[] = array(
                        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy2,
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $term2,
                );
            }
            if( 1 < count($tax_query) ){
                $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
            }
       }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_posts_filter_frontend' );
```

The $_GET parameters added to the address will filter the listed posts.

Like `[Taxonomy slug value]=[Term slug value]`, example:

Custom posts with "`Color`" taxonomy value "`Red`":

`host.tld/my-post-type-slug/?color=red`

Custom posts with "`Color`" taxonomy value is "`Red`" and "`Size`" taxonomy value is "`Small`":

`host.tld/my-post-type-slug/?color=red&size=small`

If SEO-compatible URL addresses are important for you, you can improve the code for URL redirection.